# Importing Excel csv file into RStudio & converting factors to numeric, I get either NAs or new data; tried eliminating commas but still get NAs

Tags: r, excel, csv, rstudio

the Excel csv data file (called ff) has 54 columns & 788 rows of normalized data between 0 & 1, that looks like this: 0.39   0.16    0.27    0.60 ...

```
> str(ff)
'data.frame':   788 obs. of  54 variables:
$ V1 : Factor w/ 66 levels " -   "," 0.05 ",..: 25 36 33 44 36 37 39 20

> dd <- as.numeric(as.character(ff))

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion


> dd <- gsub(".","",ff)
> de <- as.numeric(as.character(dd))
> str(de)
num [1:54] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I'm at a loss.  I saw that lots of folks (perhaps beginners like me) have posted somewhat similar questions, please accept my apologies for raising this matter again.  My gratitude in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You have elements like `" -   "`.  The warning message is a friendly one and it is converting those elements to NA

Comment: set `colClasses` to numeric when reading

Comment: @user7403680 are you still interested in this? Has anything here helped you, or are you still having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem you're having is that you're running the `as.numeric(as.character(.))` call on an entire data frame, rather than a particular column. The result is a vector, the length of which equals the number of columns in your data frame (note your output is a vector of length 54, rather than 788 like you'd be hoping for from a column of your original data frame). Here's why:

When you convert a data frame to character, you get a vector back:

```
df <- data.frame( V1 = c(1,2,3), V2 = c(4,5,6) )
as.character( df )
[1] "c(1, 2, 3)" "c(4, 5, 6)"
```

Note that each vector element is not a character vector (ie: `c("1","2","3")`), but is in fact the vector representing that column, converted to a character string (ie: `"c(1, 2, 3)"`). So when you apply `as.numeric` to that vector, you'll get a vector back (not a data frame), and since each element can't be converted to a number (or even a numeric vector), you get `NA`s back:

```
as.numeric( as.character( df ) )
[1] NA NA
```

What you're more likely looking for is a conversion for a single column, rather than the entire data frame. Try:

```
ff$V1 <- as.numeric( as.character( ff$V1 ) )
```

This way you're converting a vector to a vector, which should give you the result you're after. You can do this over every column using `lapply`, something like:

```
df <- lapply( df, function(x) as.numeric( as.character( x ) ) )
df <- as.data.frame( df )
```

(or better yet, set the `colClasses` when you read the file as per @s.brunel's comment, such that you don't need to worry about this conversion at all)

NOTE also @akrun's comment. You should *expect* a warning when converting a vector where some values can't be converted to the class you're wanting. In your case, you've got some `" -  "` values, which can't be converted to numeric, so you'll get `NA`s in place of those.